How can I run a Python function without loading a page in Django
I am working on a project which contains a function that generates a response automatically on loop using Google's Gemini API and sends it to the HTML page by saving it to the database, I want this function to run behind the scenes without loading the page.
Currently what is happening is, if the function generates 10 responses in a loop it then keeps loading the page until all responses are generated and then, it is rendering the home.html page.
This is the function:
def home(request):
    print("Bot: Hello how can i help you?")

    i = 0
    while i < 2:
        if len(history_global) == 0:
            user_input = input("You: ")
            chat_session = model.start_chat(
            history=history
            )

            response = chat_session.send_message(user_input)                        #1 Taking input from user
            
            model_response = response.text
            
            history.append({"role" : "user", "parts" : [user_input]})              #3 updating history - (user part)
            history.append({"role" : "model", "parts" : [model_response]})         #4 updating history - (response part)
            history_global = model_response                                        #5 updating value of history_global with the response created

            # Save the data to the database
            saveit = Data1(question=user_input, answer=history_global)
            saveit.save()
          
            print(i)
            print("Question : ", user_input)
            print()
            print("Answer : ", model_response)
            print()
            print("...............................................................................................1")
            print()

            random_interval = random.randint(10, 15)
            time.sleep(random_interval)

        else:
            chat_session = model.start_chat(
                history=history
            )

            new_prompt = "[make any one question from the following content] - " + history_global

            response = chat_session.send_message(new_prompt)                      #1 Taking input from previous response
                                                                                  # generating output result (basically question).......
            model_response = response.text                                        #2 Generated question
            history_global_question = model_response

            history.append({"role" : "user", "parts" : [new_prompt]})              #3 updating history - (user part)
            history.append({"role" : "model", "parts" : [model_response]})         #4 updating history - (response part)
            history_global = model_response                                        #5 updating value of history_global
           
            random_interval_01 = random.randint(10, 15)
            time.sleep(random_interval_01)

            response2 = chat_session.send_message(history_global_question)         #6 Taking question generated in #2 as a prompt
            model_response2 = response2.text                                       #7 Generated answer

            history.append({"role" : "user", "parts" : [user_input]})              #8 updating history - (user part)
            history.append({"role" : "model", "parts" : [model_response]})         #9 updating history - (response part)
            history_global = model_response2                                       #10 updating history_global with new response

            # Save the data to the database
            saveit = Data1(question=history_global_question, answer=model_response2)
            saveit.save()

            print(i)
            print("Question : ", history_global_question)
            print()
            print("Answer : ", model_response2)
            print()
            print("...............................................................................................2")
            print()
            
            random_interval = random.randint(10, 15)
            time.sleep(random_interval)
            
        i+=1

    data1 = Data1.objects.all()

    context = {"data_test" : data1}

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

Here is index.html
{% load static %}
<!-- main/templates/home.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to our website</h1>

    {% for data1 in data_test %}
    <div>
        <h1 style="color: antiquewhite;">{{data1.question_html}}</h1>
        <br>
        <p style="color: aqua;">{{data1.answer_html}}</p>
        <a href="contentpage/{{data1.id}}">click here</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>

</html>




With a management command?

how does it work

Try searching for Django single page application.

okay i learned ablout how to make custom command, but how i run this command automatically while running a server, i mean how this command will automatically execute while server is running

enter code here seems to be invalid python code and throws a Syntax error

That is not the part of code

If I were  you I would consider using Celery a powerful asynchronous task queue for Python. It allows you to run functions in the background without blocking your main web request or causing the page to hang.
Here’s a basic approach (You can find more in the docs)
Install Celery and a message broker like Redis
Move your response-generating loop into a Celery task
Trigger the task from your Django view without waiting for it to complete.
